# Image Icon not showing on JButton

Tags: java, user-interface, jbutton, packaging, imageicon

I'm currently making a game in java and have a JButton which has an image icon.  The only problem is the image is not shown and not even an error is thrown in the debug window.

I have packaged my program (see screenshot - https://db.tt/N9CwHJdf).  The code I have used is written below, if anyone could resolve this problem I'd really appreciate it.  Thank you.

```
//Button Image
ImageIcon diceIcon = new ImageIcon("Client/images/DiceIcon.png");

//Create Button
JButton rollDice = new JButton("Roll Dice", diceIcon);
rollDice.setForeground(Color.darkGray);
rollDice.setFocusPainted(false);
rollDice.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(284,50));
rollDice.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.orange));
rollDice.setBackground(Color.orange);
rollDice.setToolTipText("Click to roll dice and continue playing");
rollDice.addActionListener(this);
```

Comment: DiceIcon = new ImageIcon("Client/images/DiceIcon.png"); try giving the full image path

Comment: I've added the following line: DiceIcon = new ImageIcon("src/Client/images/DiceIcon.png"); and that still doesn't work :(

Comment: Try getting the path from the beginning file in your project, and see if that works...images are tricky when it comes to pathways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load your ImageIcon like this:

```
ImageIcon diceIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/DiceIcon.png"));
```

Read the Java Tutorial on [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) for more.

Comment: I have the same problem.
But in my case, it has to look like this(copy the code):

`ImageIcon diceIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/DiceIcon.png"));
static JButton mybutton = new JButton("mybutton", diceIcon);


public static void main(String[] args) {

add(mybutton);
}`

But then it underlines getClass() and shows error, because it's static.
Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: @Tom Lenc: Try this:

    import javax.swing.*;
    public class Foo extends JFrame {
        private ImageIcon diceIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/DiceIcon.png"));
       private JButton mybutton = new JButton("mybutton", diceIcon);

       public Foo(){
           add(mybutton);
           pack();
       }
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           new Foo().setVisible(true);
       }
}

Comment: that doesn't work.
I have to add that button after specific part after main method and that mean that the mybutton has to be static, which means that the ImageIcon has to be static too, but then I throws an error.
It's hard to explain..(I'm not american)

Comment: The problem with this is that you can not use getClass() in a static context, since it is a non-static method. You could bypass this restriction if you skip getClass() and getResource() and write: private static ImageIcon diceIcon = new ImageIcon("/images/DiceIcon.png");, but then the compiler will get you when you try to add(mybutton); since add is also not-static.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use `ImageIcon.getImageLoadStatus()` to make sure the image loaded without errors before attempting to render it on a `JButton`.

Answer (score 0):

[javas.swing.Action](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html) is a sort of *ugly duckling* class in Java GUI API: not much used and very few examples for correct use, despite its interesting proposal.

When using an ***Action*** in a button, you can define several properties you would usually have to add one by one directly to button instance, as the icon, tooltip, caption, etc.

***An annoying issue is that Action overrides your button settings with a warning!*** So, if you use Action, avoid setting extra properties.

You can define your own Action factory class or extend [AbstractAction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractAction.html) and use [putValue(String key, Object value)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractAction.html#putValue-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) to set your button properties, as shown in the code snippet below.

Please, make sure you are using the keys defined in the Action class when setting your own values with putValues().

```
**
* Facility class for AbstractAction
* Remember that Action also extends ActionListener interface
*
*/
class MyAction extends AbstractAction {     
/**
 * Ctor.
 * @param name - The Action.NAME or the button caption
 * @param actionCMD - the Action.ACTION_COMMAND_KEY value
 * @param shortDescription - the tool tip, Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION
 * @param icon - the default icon, or  Action.SMALL_ICON paramenter.
 */
public MyAction(String name, String actionCMD, String shortDescription, Icon icon) {                   
     putValue(Action.NAME, name);  
     putValue(Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION, shortDescription);  
     putValue(Action.ACTION_COMMAND_KEY, actionCMD);  
     if(icon != null)
         putValue(Action.SMALL_ICON, icon);
 }  

 /**
  * The action to be performed
  */
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {  
    // put your action code here
 }  
} // end class
```